# Powebi: new table based on filtered data from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create new table based on data in another table im powerbi.
Output table should contain columns:
Name,
Month,
Number of Items - total count of items equal to true,
Numer of Items2 - total count of items2 equal to true

Sample base table:

```
| Name | Month | Items | Items2 |
| ---- | ----- |------ | ------ |
| Ala  | 01    | true  | false  |
| Ala  | 01    | true  | false  |
| Ala  | 02    | true  | false  |
| Ala  | 01    | false | true   |
| Ala  | 02    | false | true   |
| Ola  | 01    | false | false  |
| Ola  | 02    | true  | true   |
| Ola  | 01    | false | true   |
```

Output table should look like this

```
| Name | Month |Nb of Items | Nb of Items2 |
| ---- | ----- |------------| ------------ |
| Ala  | 01    | 2          | 1            |
| Ala  | 02    | 1          | 1            |
| Ola  | 01    | 0          | 1            |
| Ola  | 02    | 1          | 1            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMMARIZE to group by Name and Month.
Then CALCULATE will change the context of the calculation to count the number of rows for Items = TRUE() and Items2 = TRUE() separately :

```
NewTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    MyTable,
    MyTable[Name],
    MyTable[Month],
    "Nb of Items", CALCULATE(IF(COUNTROWS(MyTable) == BLANK() ,0,COUNTROWS(MyTable)) , MyTable[Item] = TRUE()),
    "Nb of Items2", CALCULATE(IF(COUNTROWS(MyTable) == BLANK() ,0,COUNTROWS(MyTable)) , MyTable[Item2] = TRUE())
)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you tell me also how I can trim start string from the column e.g. I have "Month 01" but instead I would like to get 01? I have some text in month column which I would like to skip in output table

Comment: Validate the answer then open a new question with what you need to achieve.